# Is there a Visual Studio 2019 way to combine solutions?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, projects-and-solutions

It used to be that when I would go to the open project/solution dialog, I would get:

[image: Options: Add to Solution, Close Solution]

But now in VS 2019, these options are gone. How do I perform this same task in 2019 (dump all the projects from one solution into the other)?

Answer (score 3):

I was just about to post my question when I had an idea, and it turns out to be the answer:

1. In the Solution Explorer, right-click on the currently-open solution (the one you want to dump projects **into**).
2. Add->Existing project: [image]
3. Change the file type/extension drop-down to Solution Files (*.sln).
4. Select the solution to import projects **from** and import away!

Comment: There is no way to select *.sln in VS2019 or VS2022.

Comment: If you type '*.sln' into the Open Project dialog, it will accept that as a filter, even though it doesn't appear in the filter drop-down.

Comment: many thanks, this works like a charm. Altough the functionality is hidden **very** well :-)

Comment: Does not work for VS 2022. At first - all like Mark Kreitler says: 
(1) Solution -> Add -> Existing Project
(2) In the `Add Existing Project` dialog, navigate to the folder where `*.sln` file is located
(3) In the `File Name:` textbox type `*.sln` and click the `Open` button. 
Now you see the solution file. However, opening it shows "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Oops.